# Serve index.html at root (and ONLY at root) in Spring Boot app

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot app, in which I configure some static resources like this:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/path/to/static/resources/");
    }
}
```

Now I want:

1. "/" to serve "index.html" from the resource folder and
2. "/index.html" to redirect to "/"

How do I do that?